# Using AND OR in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which has `PRODUCTCODE_`, `ACCOUNTNUMBER_` and `TYPE`_  as columns.

I have a record with

- **PCBB02** as value for `PRODUCTCODE_`.
- **DepositAccount** as value for `TYPE_`
- **98** as value for `ACCOUNTNUMBER_`

I did a query as bellow :

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE 1=1
  AND (TYPE_ = 'DepositAccount' AND PRODUCTCODE_ <> 'PABB01' AND PRODUCTCODE_ <> 'PABB05')
   OR (TYPE_ = 'DepositAccount' AND PRODUCTCODE_ = 'PCBB02' AND ACCOUNTNUMBER_  = '98')
```

When I delete the first AND query the line is not shown (which is what I want) but with the query below the line will be included in the result.

So, the problem is a mess of use of the AND / OR in the query. What is the right query?

Exmp:

```
PRODUCTCODE_    TYPE_        ACCOUNTNUMBER_
PCBB02        DepositAccount      90
PCXXX         DepositAccount      00
```

Expected Result : Row 2

Current Result :  Row 1 and Row 2

Comment: Show sample data and expected output. What are you trying to do? Because we cant guess what is wrong just because you say doesnt show. You should explain the logic you are trying to apply. You are probably asking the wrong question [**What is the XY problem?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers

Comment: Can you explain the logic you want? first condition is true because both code are `<> ('PABB01', ' PABB05')`btw, you can put a single `TYPE_ = 'DepositAccount'` because both condition use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the placeholder "1=1"

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
WHERE (TYPE_ = 'DepositAccount' AND PRODUCTCODE_ <> 'PABB01' AND PRODUCTCODE_ <> 'PABB05')
OR  (TYPE_ = 'DepositAccount' AND PRODUCTCODE_ = 'PCBB02' AND ACCOUNTNUMBER_  = '98')
```

Comment: Still same problem

Comment: you get both row 1 and row 2 since PRODUCTCODE_ is not 'PABB01' AND PRODUCTCODE_ also is not 'PABB05'

Answer (score 0):

problem number 1 is your 1=1 that doesn't belong so when you delete the first AND you really have 1=1 (TYPE_.....) which isn't right.  Remove it if you want to remove the AND.  As far as what results you actually want you need to specify more clearly what result you do want so we can better assist you.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE
(TYPE_ = 'DepositAccount' AND PRODUCTCODE_ <> 'PABB01' AND PRODUCTCODE_ <> 'PABB05')
OR  (TYPE_ = 'DepositAccount' AND PRODUCTCODE_ = 'PCBB02' AND ACCOUNTNUMBER_  = '98')
```

Next you can acutally USE NOT IN to list multiple product codes as once that you don't want it equal to it will make it a little easier to read.  And because DepositAccount Type is in both that can be a condition on its own.  Also because 'PCBB02' is NOT IN 01 & 05 your or statement is just redundant and not necessary:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE
TYPE_ = 'DepositAccount'
AND PRODUCTCODE_ NOT IN ('PABB01','PABB05')
```

And if you really just want the record 02 with 98 Then you can do as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE
TYPE_ = 'DepositAccount' AND PRODUCTCODE_ = 'PCBB02' AND ACCOUNTNUMBER_  = '98'
```

**Per your comment**
That can be written several ways here is one that is a little easier to understand.  The use of NOT prior to a condition will exclude when true from your result set.  Note PRODUCTCODE_ = 'PABB02' will still be returned if the account number is not '98'

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE
TYPE_ = 'DepositAccount'
AND PRODUCTCODE_ NOT IN ('PABB01','PABB05')
AND NOT (PRODUCTCODE_ = 'PABB02' AND ACCOUNTNUMBER_ = '98')
```

Is ACCOUNTNUMBER_ really a numeric data type?  if so you should remove the single quotes surrounding the number.

Comment: In my table I have more than 1M records and , yes I want all the records that verify all the conditions.

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd what conditions?  Your 2 statments are redunand of eachother you either want everything that is not PABB01/05 that is a DepositAccount.  which is my second example and would inlcude PCBB02 if 02 is a deposit account.  Do you only want to include 02 if Account number is 98?  spend some time editing your question with your actual business requirements as they are not clear

Comment: The recors must verify the conditions : that productcode is different from 'PABB01' and 'PABB05' and in the case the product code = 'PCBB02' the accountnumber must be different from 98

Comment: answer is updated.  And the explanation in your comment should be within your question it is not evident as a requirement from your code and narrative